# Why we use spread operator into redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen the following code:

```
export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            };

        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                items: action.payload.products
            };

        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.error,
                items: []
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But don't understand why do we use ...state every time for each case.

Can't we just write:

```
return {
                    loading: false,
                    error: action.payload.error,
                    items: action.payload.products
                };
```

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: it's not mandatory, it's used to keep previous existing keys

Comment: Documentation reference: https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator or one step further: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because commonly you want to keep other keys inside your state...

If your state has:

```
{
   items:['a', 'b', 'c'],
   loading: false,
   error: null
}
```

and you only return for example:

```
case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
    return {
        // ...state, --> Without this line
        loading: true,
        error: null
    };
```

Your new state will be

```
{
    loading: true,
    error: null
}
```

And your `items` will be lost.

Then, returning:

```
case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
    };
```

You are saying

> Return a copy of state, but overriding `loading` and `error` keys"

Answer (score 1):

This is for creating new copied state object with new or updated values (without this you would need manually specify every state field).

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can be used as alternative

[Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator) has really good explanation about using spread operator.